# Conditions for $\big\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\big\}=\big\{\{x\},\{y\},\{z\}\big\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, contest-math

Let $a,b,c,x,y,z$ be any real numbers. I want to show that $\big\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\big\}=\big\{\{x\},\{y\},\{z\}\big\}$ if and only if
\begin{align*}
x+y+z & =a+b+c \\
xy+xz+yz & =ab+ac+bc  \\
xyz & =abc
\end{align*}
Clearly if $\big\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\big\}=\big\{\{x\},\{y\},\{z\}\big\}$ the previous equalities hold. How could I prove the converse ? Any help or hint is very much appreciated.

Comment: Remember Vieta's relations.

Comment: It's only true if $a,b,c$ are distinct. For example,  $\{1,1,2\}=\{1,2,2\}$ but the formulas are not true.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: is the first equation true for that example?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Right! Perhaps asking instead for $\{\{a\},\{b\}\{c\} \}=\{\{x\},\{y\}\{z\}\}$ fixes the issue without asking $a,b,c$ to be distinct.

Comment: What is the first question? $\{1,1,2\}=\{1,2,2\}$ under the usual meaning of those symbols. @CarlMummert

Comment: @LeoSera Don't think that $a \mapsto \{a\}$ changes much there. The more common way to phrase it would be "*the triplets (or tuples) are identical up to permutation*".

Comment: @Leo Sera: $\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\} = \{\{x\},\{y\},\{z\}\}$ if and only if $\{a,b,c\} = \{x,y,z\}$. For example, assuming the first equation, we have $\{a\}$ as a member of $\{\{x\},\{y\},\{z\}\}$, so $a \in \{x,y,z\}$, and conversely if $a \in \{x,y,z\}$ then $\{a\} \in \{\{x\}, \{y\}, \{z\}\}$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: I overlooked the word "not" in your comment - apologies. That does give a correct counterexample, of course, with $a = 1$, $b =1$,  $c = 2$, $x = 1$, $y = 2$, $z = 2$.  I had been looking for a counterexample at the time, so I was interested in yours.

Comment: @Leo Sera: as  Thomas Andrews points out, the sentence beginning "clearly" isn't right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll take the liberty of rephrasing the question according to what it *probably* means, since it seems to me that the OP is missing the technical tools to phrase it correctly:

> Let $(x,y,z)$ and $(a,b,c)$ be two triplets of complex numbers. Prove that $$(a,b,c)\in\{(x,y,z),\,(x,z,y),\,(y,x,z),\,(y,z,x),\,(z,x,y),\,(z,y,x)\}$$ if and only if $$\begin{cases} x+y+z=a+b+c\\ xy+xz+yz=ab+ac+bc\\ xyz=abc\end{cases}$$

The non-obvious implication is: consider the polynomials $p(T)=(T-a)(T-b)(T-c)$ and $q(T)=(T-x)(T-y)(T-z)$. If you run the calcs, you'll notice that your condition is exactly $p=q$. According to your knowledge of algebra, you should know that the roots of a polynomial are well-defined.

Comment: I knew that the condition seemed familiar. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, though, because just because two polynomials have the same *set* of roots does not mean that they are the same polynomial; the multiplicities would also need to be the same.